# Strange Error for dom element properties and events

Tags: dart, dart-html

So I have been getting this type of error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
  https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/components/doodle-notifier-01.html
Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a getter 'onClick'.

This is my Html:

```
<label for="stringToEncode">Encode a String to Base64</label>
<input type="text" id="stringToEncode">
<button type="button" id="submit">Encode</button>
```

Very simple right now. I am working towards a more ambitious end.

This is my dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var dataEncode = querySelector('stringToEncode');
  var submit = querySelector('submit');

  submit.onClick.listen((e) {
    String convert = dataEncode.value;
    var output = querySelector('output');

    if(convert != null) {
      var base = window.btoa(convert);
      output.text = "$base";
    } else {
      window.alert("you need to enter something into the input");
    }
  });
}
```

Just trying to do some simple encoding of the input value upon the click of the submit button. I plan to try to do this with images later, but I decided to start small. This is beside the point.

Why do I get the error: 

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
  https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/components/doodle-notifier-01.html
Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a getter 'onClick'." for a simple onClick event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use querySelector for the `submit` element, but you defined your button as `<button type="button" id="submit">Encode</button>`. And you are missing a `#` at `querySelector('stringToEncode');`.

Comment: Thank you. I should have spotted that